# AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'WorkingHours'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, constructor

Why an attribute error is coming? WorkingHours attribue is not found?

```
class Employee:
    def numberofWorkingHours(self):
        self.WorkingHours = 45

    def printnumberofWorkingHours(self):
        print(self.WorkingHours)

class Trainee:
 def numberofWorkingHours(self):
     self.WorkingHours = 60

emp = Employee()
emp.printnumberofWorkingHours()
```

Comment: Please post the whole error in the question.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Call `emp.numberofWorkingHours()` first to set it.

Comment: Calling emp.numberofWorkingHours() first to set it, resolved my issue. @JohnnyMopp Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place where you are setting `self.WorkingHours` is inside the body of the method `numberofWorkingHours`.

Since in your demo you never call the method, the attribute `WorkingHours` is not set.

You can either call `numberofWorkingHours` beforehand or redesign your class. A better approach would be to set `self.WorkingHours = 45` in the `__init__` method. (You could also consider not hardcoding the value, but passing it to `__init__` as on optional argument, e.g. `def __init__(self, WorkingHours=45): ...`.)

Comment: Thanks! For such a descriptive answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self):
        self.WorkingHours = 45

    def printnumberofWorkingHours(self):
        print(self.WorkingHours)

class Trainee:
    def numberofWorkingHours(self):
        self.WorkingHours = 60

emp = Employee()
emp.printnumberofWorkingHours()
```

Replace numberofWorkingHours method with `__init__`